# How to add a new authenticated user in Mosquitto using Java

Tags: java, authentication, mqtt, mosquitto, broker

I configurated my local Mosquitto so it only accepts on port 8883 authenticated users using TLS protocol.

Currently I created some users with their passwords in a "passwd" file which I linked do mosquitto.conf file so it can recognize the authenticated users.

Can I write some code in Java which allows me to modify runtime the "passwd" file so I can automatically add a new user with his password so he can start to use Mosquitto without force an administrator to modify manually the passwd file?

Answer (score 4):

In order to have mosquitto re-read the passwd file you will either need to restart mosquitto after each change (which will disconnect all current users) or send mosquitto a HUP signal to trigger it to re-read the file.

A **MUCH** better solution is to use mosquitto's plugin system to read users/acls from a database that can be updated dynamically.

Also as of Mosquitto v2.x there is the built in dynamic security plugin that allows you to create new users by sending MQTT messages. Details of this can be found [here](https://mosquitto.org/documentation/dynamic-security/)

Comment: I created the "dynamic-security.json" file with admin user and it works. How could I link a user database to Mosquitto? Should I insert the users in the "dynamic-security.json" file? Or is there another way?

Comment: There are 2 separate suggestions in this answer, 1) use one of the 3rd party plugins that support databases. 2) use the Dynamic Security plugin to add users via MQTT messages. These are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Example database auth plugin https://github.com/iegomez/mosquitto-go-auth

Answer (score 0):

In the configuration for the broker add a class that implements **IAuthenticator**.

Example.

```
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty(BrokerConstants.AUTHENTICATOR_CLASS_NAME,IAuthenticatorImp.class.getName());
    properties.setProperty(BrokerConstants.ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_PROPERTY_NAME,"false");
    // More properties
    final IConfig config = new MemoryConfig(properties);
```

The class implements IAuthenticator can be like this.

```
import io.moquette.broker.security.IAuthenticator;

public class IAuthenticatorImp implements IAuthenticator {    
    @Override
    public boolean checkValid(String clientId, String userCheck, byte[] passwordCheck) {
       // Here validate the user authentication 
       // TRUE correct and FLASE denied 
       return true;
    }
}
```

And maven dependece

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.moquette</groupId>
    <artifactId>moquette-broker</artifactId>
    <version>0.15</version>
<dependency>
```